# Input from a text file

Tags: c, input, dev-c++

I need to make a function , which will take as input a .txt file and then proceed 
working on each character , while doing a bunch of operations.

This how function's declaration looks like.

```
int ProcessInput(FILE *in);
```

The thing is I don't want to take an input from keyboard , but from the .txt file as mentioned before. 
I am working on Dev C++ .
Any ideas ?

Comment: Open the text file and read it to process its data .

Comment: Have you decided what the return value from the function will mean?

Comment: it should be void i guess

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (2 > argc)
  {
    printf("Please enter a file name on the command line\n");
    return 0;
  }
  FILE* in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!in)
  {
    printf("Unable to open the specified file\n");
    return 0;
  }
  ProcessInput(in);
  fclose(in);
  return 0;
}
```